# Chord.setOctave(x) returns notes with wrong value in jFugue 5. what am I missing?

Tags: jfugue

Here is the sample code:

```
public class TestNoteValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chord c = new Chord("C5maj");
        DevLog.debug(MusicAnnotationUtil.reportChord(c));
        // ----------------
        c.setOctave(4);
        DevLog.debug(MusicAnnotationUtil.reportChord(c));
    }
}
```

Result output:

[image]

Result for the first time is right:
    Chord{Note{C5, 60}, Note{E5, 64}, Note{G5, 67}, }

C5's value indeed is 60.
However after Chord.setOctave(4), it doesn't change the first note's expression, however changed its value. Resulting in a correctness-compromised note array:
    Chord{**Note{C5, 48}**, Note{E4, 52}, Note{G4, 55}, }

am I missing something here?

thanks for the help!

---

As David is helping look into the code, I'll post my temporary workaround. Hopefully it helps others.

```
    public static Chord setOctave(Chord c, byte octave) {
    DevLog.super_trace("setting octave for chord "+c+" to "+octave);
    c.setOctave(octave);
    Note[] nA = new Note[3];
    for(int i=0; i<c.getNotes().length; i++){
        nA[i] = new Note(c.getNotes()[i].getValue());
    }
    return Chord.fromNotes(nA);
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the notes E5 and G5 were changed to E4 and G4! I suspect the problem might be in the way that the Note class generates its toString() output. There's a lot of complexity in there about the string used to create a note versus octave that may or not be manually set. I'll look into it!

Comment: thanks for the effort! i'll be looking forward to the result. Fortunately values are correct. I just added my workaround for now above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new method to the Note class that updates the "original string" with which a note was created when the value of that note is changed.

I'll release a new version after touching up some other issues. In the meantime, here's what has changed in Note.java:

Updated method:

```
public Note setValue(byte value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.updateOriginalString(); // New line that calls the method below
    return this;
}
```

New method:

```
private void updateOriginalString() {
    if (this.getOriginalString() != null) {
        String oldOriginalString = this.getOriginalString();
        StringBuilder newOriginalString = new StringBuilder();
        newOriginalString.append(getToneString());
        if ((oldOriginalString.length() > 1) && (oldOriginalString.substring(oldOriginalString.length()-2, oldOriginalString.length()-1).matches("\\d"))) {
            newOriginalString.append(getOctave());
        }
        setOriginalString(newOriginalString.toString());
    }
}
```

And a new test in NoteTest.java:

```
@Test
public void testOriginalStringForNotes() {
    assertTrue(new Note("C").getOriginalString().equals("C"));
    assertTrue(new Note("C5").getOriginalString().equals("C5"));
    assertTrue(new Note("C").changeValue(+1).getOriginalString().equals("C#"));
    assertTrue(new Note("C5").changeValue(+1).getOriginalString().equals("C#5"));
    assertTrue(new Note("C").setValue((byte)48).getOriginalString().equals("C"));
    assertTrue(new Note("C5").setValue((byte)48).getOriginalString().equals("C4"));
}
```